# How can I send JSON insead of HTML from PHP?

Tags: php, html, json

I need to change working PHP method, that is parsing SMS to send JSON instead of HTML. I am re-creating front-end to Vue.js and I have hard time showing HTML there.
Problem is that I don't have any ideas how to do it, what to do and how it should looks.

May I please ask you to help me figure how that should be done? Like I need inspiration, because there are so many conditions and stuff and I really have no idea how to do it.

For example, here is code that is returning HTMML.

Look at that part where are if statements.
How can I change it to return json?

I am new to back-end and also never worked with PHP, that is why I need inspiration.

Thank you!

```
$par = explode(';', caesarCipher($m[1], -3));

hzsGetSMSPosition()

if ($par[0] == '')
    $par[0] = 'x';

$ret = hzsGetSMSPosition($par, $sender, 'cz');
if ($par[6] != '')
    $ret[0] .= 'Nadm. výška: ' . hsc($par[6]) . ' m' . $nl;

$terajsi_stav = array();
$par[25] .= '000000000000000000';
if ($par[25][0] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'ťažký úraz';
if ($par[25][1] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'autonehoda so zranením';
if ($par[25][2] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'bolesť na hrudi';
if ($par[25][3] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'ťažké krvácanie';
if ($par[25][4] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'alergická reakcia';
if ($par[25][5] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'dýchavičnosť';
if ($par[25][6] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'iný problém / bolesť brucha';
if ($par[25][7] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'bezvedomie';
if ($par[25][8] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'svedok';
if ($par[25][9] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'lavína';
if ($par[25][10] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'uviaznutie';
if ($par[25][11] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'zablúdenie';
if ($par[25][12] == '1') $terajsi_stav[] = 'zranenie v horách';
if (!empty($terajsi_stav))
    $ret[0] .= 'Aktuálny stav: ' . implode(', ', $terajsi_stav) . $nl;
```

Comment: `hzsGetSMSPosition()` should generate an error! So what is really the issue here

Comment: It is not complete function. It is only part of it because it is like 400 lines.

Comment: So turn it into an [mcve], as per the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask). If you have a ton of code, almost none of it will actually be _related_ to the problem, and you should be able to just omit it entirely, and reducing any necessary duplication or elaboration to just enough to still reproduce the problem. In this case, if the question is "how do I send json", then really the MCVE code would be maybe three or four lines, if any even.

Answer (score 1):

[json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) is perfect for your needs

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: provided you also remember to set your response headers correctly, because it now has the content-type "application/json", not "text/html".

Comment: So I create array and then just  assing values to it? 
Example: 
`
<?php
$arr = array('sender' => '0909 123 456', 'name' => 'John', 'surname' => 'Doe', 'problems' => 'high blood sugar');

echo json_encode($arr);
?>`

and then just update values?